# How do I automatically move artifacts from Team City to virtual directories?

Tags: teamcity, build-server

Team city publishes its artifacts to a dynamically changing URL-- the version and build number keeps incrementing.

How can I automate the download of such a file?

Does team city even have a feature that I'm not aware of for automatically moving artifacts from the build server's artifact repository to the staging/test server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this, Team City has a Deployer plugin which supports moving artifacts to a Samba share, FTP server or SSH server: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin

Comment: How did you managed to access the artifact? When I refer to them via the *Path to sources* field within SSH Upload I am not able to receive it. I opened a question to this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330079/teamcity-ssh-upload-build-step-can-not-find-artifacts-of-dependency-build

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is bake the publishing / copying /deployment (ie- downloading) of things directly into the build script that TeamCity uses instead of setting things up as artifacts.

Alternatively, you could set up a new build config that would automatically start after your first build is done.  It would take your project's artifacts as dependencies and publish them.

Comment: Heya. Already made a question out of that approach. I want to use the Build Step `SSH Upload` to publish the artifact I should receive because I have an `Artifact Depdencency` and the previous build process. It does not work. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330079/teamcity-ssh-upload-build-step-can-not-find-artifacts-of-dependency-build?noredirect=1#comment93553262_53330079 for details